# "The bigger they are." by itself

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions

I am wondering if the sentence below is correct to use in (informal) speaking.

> "I don't like to be famous, the bigger you are."

I have purposefully omitted the second part of the phrase to seem more native.

Of course the full proverb is "The bigger they are, the harder they fall".

I know that one can use "the bigger they are." but here to fit this phrase to my sentence, I think I need to change "they" to "you". Am I correct? Can you drop the second half of the proverb like I did in my sentence?

Comment: You can say just about anything in an informal register, but you'll need shared context to bridge any semantic gaps. In the case of your quote, I'm not sure what relationship you're drawing between size and a (lack of) fondness for fame. Until that is established, the change in pronoun is a lesser concern.

Comment: Sorry,but I don't understand what you need by "I'm not sure what relationship you're drawing between size and a (lack of) fondness for fame"  @Lawrence

Comment: The first part is an absolute ("I don't like") whereas the second part is relative ("the bigger"). What's the connection? I don't have enough context to understand what you're trying to say with that quote, so it looks like a non-sequitur. You might say "the bigger you are the less I want to be famous" or "I don't like to be famous (any more) now that you are so big", but with the existing quote, there's something missing - kind of like "the bigger you are, the (*what?*) something is".

Comment: Native speakers usually say "The bigger they are" instead of saying "The bigger they are, the harder they fall". That is ok in that sense. @Lawrence

Comment: Ah, you'll need different punctuation to bring that out. E.g. "I don't like to be famous. The bigger you are ...". Otherwise, the "bigger" part looks like it's intended to qualify the "famous" part.

Comment: OoPS! Is it correct to say "I don't like to be famous because the bigger you are" @Lawrence

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the correct correct form of saying that? I want to say: "I don't like to be famous because the bigger you are the harder you fall " @Lawrence

Comment: @HolgerMate No it is not correct to say "X because the bigger you are." The pattern is  "The Yer (something), the Zer (something else)" which is translated to  the German "Je mehr Y (something), desto mehr (something else)" (or some other some other comparitives). It really requires a second phrase, the first one doesn't stand alone. Like with any phrasing, one may elide things if you indicate in speech that something else would follow. One would write out the informal statement: "I don't want to be famous because, you know, the bigger they are..." with the appropriate intonation.

Comment: @HolgerMate The most natural is "I don't _want_ to be famous because the bigger you are, the harder you fall." Either 'they' or 'you' work fine.

Comment: I've put my thoughts on this into an answer. Please [edit] your question to say that your quote's "bigger" references the idiom "The bigger they are, the harder they fall."

Comment: nitpicking: the title of your question does not cohere with the question in your post. [By the way, the word below comes after the noun...]

Comment: Do you mean using the complete phrase is more natural in speaking?! Is it really?! Because I have heard native speaker who don't usually use the second part of the phrase! @Mitch

Comment: @HolgerMate Sure, with any kind of proverb or any idiom (in _any_ language_) there can be some elision, the first part is enough to remind the user of the rest. "Don't count your chickens...". "A stitch in time...". "Glass houses". But the native speaker is intoning them such that the continued phrase could follow, rather than as a single constituent phrase. "I'm not sure about our success because 'don't count your chickens'" is ungrammatical as is.

Comment: You can say anything you want. Whether it will be understood as anything more than nonsense is something else. If the people you're talking to understand you, then you can can call your usage *correct*. Otherwise, you can't. Personally, if you hadn't explained what you were trying to say, I wouldn't have had a clue what you were trying to say. To me, "I have personally omitted X to seem more native" has the opposite effect in this case. Contrary to your claim, I would say that native speakers do *not* do this.

Answer (score 4):

You're referencing an *anapodoton*. Specifically, "The bigger they are, the harder they fall."

> As an intentional rhetorical device, it is generally used for set phrases, where the full form is understood, and would thus be tedious to spell out, as in "When in Rome [do as the Romans]." or "If the mountain won't come to Muhammad [Muhammed will go to the mountain]."
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapodoton)

First, the syntax needs to isolate the shortened part so that it is clear that the full quote is implied, or that there's a blank that the listener should fill in. On its own, your original quote doesn't make sense. Here's a possible rewrite using an ellipsis:

- I don't like to be famous. The bigger you are ....

You ask about replacing "they" from the original "the bigger they are ..." with "you" in your quote. However, the syntax suggests that the (second person) "you" should really refer to the first person. If we accept the [tuism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tuism)(?) - *and it does sound better in the second person than in the first person* - then the switch from "they" to "you" is acceptable in the rewritten form.

Comment: Helpful answer.  Thank you for reminding me of 'anapodoton'.  It comes from the Greek αποδιδωμι (apodidomi), meaning I render something due.  So in the question and in your example, something is promised at the beginning but not delivered as expected.  My only minor quibble is that I should have used a colon rather than a full stop.